# Can I test XBox controller UI navigation in my UWP app on a PC?

Tags: uwp, xbox

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/designing-for-tv#gamepad-and-remote-control, UWP should automatically handle directional focus when used with XBox controller. (I have set `Application.RequiresPointerMode` property to `WhenRequested`)

I have not yet actually tried to run the app on Xbox, but when run on a PC with a controller attached, UI does not react to the controller at all (other apps do).

So the question is: does XBox controller handling only work on XBox, or there's a way to enable it on a PC for testing purposes?

Comment: If you're on Anniversary or Creator update, you can simple plug your controller to PC and use it on PC as you would do on Xbox.

Comment: @NghiaNghia, behavior on Xbox in that case is different from PC. On Xbox, for example, GamepadB  without any modifications works as `Escape` button. On PC it does not.